# How to do filter with string variable?

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a SMS filter application for android. I could get my SMS' via app but when I try to add a phone number filter, app still taking all of my SMS' instead of taking SMS' from one specific phone number. Why could it be, how can I fix? 
Sharing related codes below:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle intentExtras = intent.getExtras();

        if (intentExtras != null) {
            Object[] sms = (Object[]) intentExtras.get(SMS_BUNDLE);
            String smsMessageStr = "";
            String smsBody ="";
            String address="";

            for (int i = 0; i < sms.length; ++i) {
                String format = intentExtras.getString("format");
                SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) sms[i], format);

                smsBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody().toString();
                address = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress();
                if(address.contains("490000000000")) {
                    smsMessageStr += "SMS From: " + address + "\n";
                    smsMessageStr += smsBody + "\n";
                }
            }

            MainActivity inst = MainActivity.instance();
            inst.updateInbox(smsMessageStr);

            SMSFiltering body = SMSFiltering.intent();
            body.FilterSMS(smsBody);
        }
    }



 public void FilterSMS(String smsBody){


            if(smsBody.contains("TEST"))
            {
                MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
                mainActivity.getNotified();
            }

    }
```

Comment: What is 490000000000 ?

Comment: it's a test phone number. normally, it's a real phone number, but I changed it for here since it's confidential.. I need to filter SMS' according to phone number.

Comment: Condition if(address.contains("490000000000")) returns true ?

Comment: yeah, I have several SMS came from that number